# How to return an array sorted in ascending and descending order and an array of odd or even values on PHP?

Tags: php

I have two questions regarding coding on PHP:

1. How to return an array sorted in ascending and descending order (provided as an argument), using the given array?
   (see `order` function requirement below)
2. How to return an array of odd or even values (provided as an argument), from the given array?
   (see `oddOrEven` function requirement below)

Function requirements:

```
// Sample input
$array = [8, 12, 7, 11, 77, 5];

/**
 * Custom sort function
 */
function order($array, $ascOrDesc = 'asc') {
    // sort the array according to $ascOrDesc argument
    return $array;
}

/**
 * Custom odd/even function
 */
function oddOrEven($array, $oddOrEven = 'even') {
    // find out even or odd values according to $oddOrEven argument
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: In PHP, there's [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) and [`rsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php), to sort an array in ascending or descending order. You're better off using that.

Comment: @AngelPolitis... I was using sort and rsort but i didn't arrive to the solution. I you can please

Comment: I don't understand these people, what the hell they are downvoting the OP question for?! Because it is poorly written? Or because it is a too simple question?
What is going on with you people? since when you became so snob??
I thought this platform is here to learn from each other and not to hate.
Instead of downvoting, you can give an example of how to write a correct answer.
Shame on you!

Comment: And yes, I want to help this guy to learn, but some people think that this is too broad. Remember, with great power comes great responsibility!

Comment: @Slavik Meltser ... Thank you very much. As I know no one is perfect. We come here to learn something from experienced person however things happened here is the reverse. It is unmoral. There is a lot of options at the moment to ask questions. Thanks to the technology. Really I come here because I found some genius people like you who are thinking wide. Anyways thanks again... i don't care they down voting or not.  In every direction there is a lot of open doors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) (ascending sorting) and [`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) functions to solve the first request.

```
function order($array, $ascOrDesc = 'asc') {
    switch ($ascOrDesc) {
        case 'asc':
            sort($array);
            break;
        case 'desc':
            rsort($array);
            break;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

As for the odd or even, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the desire values.

```
function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return($var & 1);
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

function oddOrEven($array, $oddOrEven = 'even') {
    if ( function_exists($oddOrEven) ) {
        return array_filter($array, $oddOrEven);
    }
    return $array;
}
```

You can use the following test cases:

```
$array = [8, 12, 7, 11, 77, 5];
print_r(order($array, 'desc'));
print_r(order($array, 'asc'));
print_r(oddOrEven($array, 'even'));
print_r(oddOrEven($array, 'odd'));
```

Comment: ...your solution is clear but  those your solution gives you the output? because when i run them, i didn't find the output

Comment: @amiega I had a typo. Just updated my answer and provided some examples.

Comment: Really I appreciate your kindness. Your answer is clear and understandable. Thanks a lot